# Static map issue

Tags: java, internet-explorer, dictionary

I have a class with a static map declared in it as

```
public class SessionMonitor {
    public static Map activeSessions = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap());
}
```

In other class when I access the map,

```
if (SessionMonitor.activeSessions.containsKey(userDTO.getUserName()) && !userDTO.getRoleMaster().getId().equals(100L)) {
    setMessage("Active session exists for this user");
    return ERROR;
}
SessionMonitor.activeSessions.put(userDTO.getUserName(), userDTO.getId());
```

When the 'IF' condition is not satisfied, it will put the element into the map as shown.
But after that the control weirdly goes back to the 'IF' condition. And this happens only when the requests are from IE. What could be wrong?

Comment: I strongly suspect that your diagnostics are wrong, but you haven't actually explained how you've diagnosed it in the first place, which makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: Most likely you have a bug in code not shown here.  The only way to repeat an action is to use recurion or a loop.

Comment: sorry. its my first time

Comment: BTW You have a race condition as you could have two+ threads not see the getUserName() and then multiple threads add the same user name.

Comment: @JonSkeet : i found out this problem while debugging in netbeans

Comment: That's still far from enough information - *how* were you debugging, what *exactly* did you observe, etc? I suspect that IE basically made a second request, but we can't tell without more information.